# How to set two placeholders in a single textbox?

Tags: html, css

I want to set two place holders in the textbox. Placeholder like (username        @domain.com) without using spaces(&nbsp) and also help for setting two backgrounds for the textbox using image sprite.

My Coding

```
background: url('sprite_images_collection_3.png') 338px -39px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The above works well. But while trying to add two backgrounds, like shown below, it is not working for me.

```
background: url('sprite_images_collection_3.png') 138px -39px;
background: url('sprite_images_collection_3.png') 338px -39px;
```

Please try to help.

Comment: For multiple backgrounds, you should use the values in a comma separated format ([refer this article](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/). If you add them as two separate property-value pairs, the second one will overwrite the first. *Note:* Browser support for this feature is pretty decent. Works in IE 9 and above.

Comment: It's working Harry.........!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Good to know mate. Could you please elaborate further on the other question about placeholders? I did not quite understand it.

Comment: K dude. Sry for my Eng. I have an another doubt. In an image its worked well. but in the text it doesn't working.  That means how to set a word space in the placeholder like (username        @domain.com) this......

Comment: Does this not work - `<input placeholder='username @domain.com'/>`?

Comment: Harry i dont want to use Space.... I need more space like            (username        domain@gmail.com) without using &nbsp.